# DrawImage on Canvas HTML5 Error

Tags: javascript, html

So when I try to draw image on canvas like this (it works fine):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 canvas</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(start);
            var image1;
            function start() {
                var ctx = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
                image1 = new Image;
                image1.src = "/arenag/arenagimg/BeastBear.jpg";
                image1.onload = function () {
                    ctx.drawImage(image1.src,200, 200, 100, 100);
                };
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #framework {
                border: 2px solid #000;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #canvas {
                background-color: #00FFE2;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="framework">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then i add a folder called imagefactory.js and create a class ImageFactory,and create function in that class called drawImage:

```
var ImageFactory = function (ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.drawImage = function (image_arg, image_x, image_y, image_w, image_h) {
        var _this = this;
        var image = new Image;
        image.src = image_arg;
        image.onload = function () {
            _this.ctx.drawImage(image.src, image_x, image_y, image_w, image_h);
        };
    };
};
```

Then I simply try to call that function in my main file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML5 canvas</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(start);
        var image;
        function start() {
            image = '/arenag/arenagimg/BeastBear.jpg';
            var ctx = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
            var imageFactory=new ImageFactory(ctx);
            imageFactory.drawImage(image,200, 200, 100, 100);
            }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #framework {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #canvas {
            background-color: #00FFE2;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="framework">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error(on 36 line in my main (HTML) file where the canvas is) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
```

And also this bug which is connected to the other one(i mean when there is no this bug then there is no the first bug too):

```
[object%20HTMLImageElement]:1 GET http://phpcasovi.dev/arenag/klase/[object%20HTMLImageElement] 404 (Not Found)
```

And i wanted to just give you a help to solve this : When i change `var image = new Image;`to `var image = {};`in JS file.Then there is no bug but becuase `var image` is not equal to `new Image` well then there is no images at all.So i think bug is at that line where i say `var image = new Image;` but i dont know why there is a bug (why should it be)??

Comment: What does `new ImageFactory` return ? Where is `onload` event ?

Comment: @Rayon Why should it return anything ?? It's quest is to just draw an image.You can see onload event here : `image.onload = function () {
            _this.ctx.drawImage(image.src, image_x, image_y, image_w, image_h);
        };` Little tip :When i change `var image = new Image;`to `var image = {};`in JS file.Then there is no bug but becuase `var image` is not equal to `new Image` well then there is no images at all.So i think bug is at that line where i say `var image = new Image;` but i dont know why there is a bug (why should it be)??

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: @Rayon Just a moment

Comment: @Rayon Here : https://jsfiddle.net/d98q0bxg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First argument for `context.drawImage` should be `Image-Object` not `image.src`

> From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage), `ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);`, **`image`**, *An element to draw into the `context`. The specification permits any `canvas image source` (`CanvasImageSource`), such as an `HTMLImageElement`, an `HTMLVideoElement`, an `HTMLCanvasElement` or an `ImageBitmap`.*

```js
var ImageFactory = function(ctx) {
  this.ctx = ctx;
  this.drawImage = function(image_arg, image_x, image_y, image_w, image_h) {
    var _this = this;
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = image_arg;
    image.onload = function() {
      _this.ctx.drawImage(image, image_x, image_y, image_w, image_h);
    };
  };
};
$(document).ready(start);

function start() {
  var image = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png';
  var ctx = $('#canvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
  var imageFactory = new ImageFactory(ctx);
  imageFactory.drawImage(image, 200, 200, 100, 100);
}
```

```css
#framework {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#canvas {
  background-color: #00FFE2;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="framework">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/d98q0bxg/1/)

Comment: Thank you really much.But still I get bug but not the first one it actually solved my question but I have another bug right now.The bug that i wrote that is connected to the first one here is the bug : `[object%20HTMLImageElement]:1 GET http://phpcasovi.dev/arenag/klase/[object%20HTMLImageElement] 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Well, in fact, you solved my problem :) Thank you I am marking this as an answer.My bug is now something really really different in my code(Nothing to do with this code at all).So thank you really much for solving my problem :) I will look for this other bug and try to solve it :) I wanted to ask you if you have skype I would like to add you on skype.My username on skype is : `siliproksi` :) Thank you again !